# How to relocate output of an executable?

Tags: bash

I have a python file named `generator.py` and this file generates some files(approximately 100) in the same location with `generator.py`. But I want the move the output files(generated files) into the `Outputs/` folder. How can I do that without change the `generator.py` file and without knowing the generated output file names?

I run my program with this command:

```
python generator.py
```

Comment: It depends on what the `generator.py` does, but probably you can do `cd Outputs; python ../generator.py`

Comment: @Zegeres, it only genereates some files. This info should be enough for my problem.

Comment: @javac : Does it really generate the files in the directory where `generator.py` is located - this would be utmost unusual -, or does it generate the files in the directory from where `generator.py` is executed? In this case, the comment by @Zereges should solve your problem.

Comment: @user1934428 it generates the files in the directory where generator.py is located.

Answer (score 1):

Since `generator.py` locates its own directory and creates its files there, I see two possibilities without fixing this insane design in the Python program (which would probably the better approach anyway). The following code assumes, that `generator.py` is locate in some directory named `gen` and we want to have his output files in a directory named `Output`:

(1) Using a reference timestamp

```
touch gen/generator.py
python gen/generator.py
find gen -cnewer gen/generator.py -exec mv gen/{} Output \;
```

(2) Use a Hack

```
cp gen/generator.py Output
python Output/generator.py
rm Output/generator.py
```

If the generator needs auxiliary files which are also in the `gen` directory, a variation of this hack is:

```
cp gen/* Output
genfiles=(Output/*)
python Output/generator.py
rm "${genfiles[@]}"
```

This assumes that the genertor does not need auxiliary files with names starting with a period ("hidden files").